# Java - NullPointerException in Graph.java

Tags: java, nullpointerexception

I am trying to create an undirected graph that is read from a text file. However I keep getting a NullPointerException. This is my Graph class:

Graph.java:

```
    package testalgo;

    import java.io.File;
    import java.util.ArrayList;
    import java.util.HashMap;
    import java.util.LinkedList;
    import java.util.List;
    import java.util.Scanner;


    public class Graph

    {   


            ArrayList<Integer> vertices = new ArrayList<Integer>();
           HashMap<Integer, LinkedList<Integer>> adj;
           static Scanner sc;
            public Graph(ArrayList<Integer> verts ){

                   adj =new HashMap<Integer, LinkedList<Integer>>();
            }

            public static void main(String[] args) {

                try{
                sc = new Scanner(new File("graph1.txt"));
                }
                catch(Exception e){

                    System.out.println(e);
                }

                while(sc.hasNext()){

                    int a = Integer.parseInt(sc.next());
                    int b = Integer.parseInt(sc.next());
                    Graph g = new Graph(new ArrayList<Integer>());
                    g.addVertex(a);
                    g.addeEgde(a, b); // this is line 46
                    g.addeEgde(b, a);


                }

                 sc.close();
            }

            public void addVertex(int v){


                for (int i = 1; i < vertices.size(); ++i) {
                adj.put(i, new LinkedList<Integer>());}

            }

            public  void addeEgde(int v1, int v2) {

                adj.get(v1).add(v2); // this is line 68
            }

            public List<Integer> getNeighbors(int v) {
                return adj.get(v);
         }
  }
```

And this is the error message that I am getting:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at testalgo.Graph.addeEgde(Graph.java:68)
    at testalgo.Graph.main(Graph.java:46)
```

Thank you for all your help!

Comment: As a side note: When I read something thats a Map of a List of a ....I think, perhaps its time to introduce some new abstractions

Answer (score 3):

I don't see anywhere in your code where you're populating the the `adj` map with `v` as a key. Hence `adj.get(v1)` will return `null`. You've only declared `adj`; you need to populate it as well.

All I see is:

```
for (int i = 1; i < vertices.size(); ++i) {
    adj.put(i, new LinkedList<Integer>());
}
```

Since `vertices` is empty to begin with, you won't be inserting anything into your map.

Did you mean:

```
adj.put(v, new LinkedList<Integer>());
```

instead?

In response to your comment: you need to add another entry for `b` in your adjacency list:

```
g.addVertex(a);
g.addVertex(b); // <--- you need this as well
g.addeEgde(a, b);
g.addeEgde(b, a); // <--- otherwise you'll get a NPE here
```

Comment: I have changed it and the error still comes up.Any ideas ? Thanks!

Comment: Did you also add an entry for `b` in your adjacency list?

Answer (score 1):

You probably have invoked `addeEdge` without having added any `vertex`, as

```
for (int i = 1; i < vertices.size(); ++i)
{
  adj.put(i, new LinkedList<Integer>());
}
```

Will not put any `LinkedList` instance in adj (`vertices.size()` is 0).

Therefore,

```
adj.get(v1).add(v2);
```

Will throw a `NullPointerException`, as `adj.get(v1)` will return `null` and you are invoking `add` on `null`.

Try declaring:

```
private static int count = 0;
```

In class body, and then, in `addVertex`:

```
adj.put(count++, new LinkedList<Integer>());
```

This one will put a new `LinkedList` in your `Map` every time `addVertex` is invoked.

Alternatively, for the map index:

```
public void addVertex(int vertexIndex)
{
  adj.put(vertexIndex, new LinkedList<Integer>());
}
```

In addition, ensure that `adj.get(v1)` will not be null by making a null check comparison before calling `add` on it:

```
LinkedList<Integer> vertex = adj.get(v1);
if(vertex != null)
{
  vertex.add(v2);
}
```

Also, cosider that g.addeEgde(b, a); applies to a vertex that does not exist and will be a source of `NullPointerException` too.

UPDATE: In the case you are attempting to insert values in a sequence (sequential index), using a `Map` for your vertexes is not the mostly efficient way of doing this (takes `O(logn)` complexity time of indexing). I suggest that you use an `ArrayList` instead:

```
ArrayList<LinkedList<Integer>> adj;
```

And in your addVertex:

```
adj.add(new LinkedList<Integer>());
```

And when indexing:

```
adj.get(yourIndex);
```

This one will be much more efficient (takes `O(1)` complexity time in indexing).

UPDATE 2: If your case is an adjacency list, which probably is, the `Map` is better to use than the `ArrayList`, as you do not have a sequential indexing.
Take in mind you must add vertices by adjacency value and NOT sequential indexing, as *Vivin Paliath* mentioned.

Comment: Thanks for your answer ! When i try                            adj.put(new LinkedList<Integer>()); I get an error.

Comment: `adj.put(new LinkedList<Integer>());` will result in a compile-time error. `Map#put` requires two arguments.

Comment: `adj` is an adjacency list. He shouldn't be setting the keys based on the **number** of vertices thus far; it should be done based on the value of the graph node.

Comment: Answer Updated again. I suggest the use of `ArrayList` as a Map will not be the most efficient in numeric indexing.

Comment: Again, your solution won't result in a proper graph-implementation. The function of an adjacency list is to maintain a list of nodes adjacent to a given node (i.e., nodes that are reachable from a vertex node). With your current implementation, how would it be possible to look up the adjacency list for a node by the value of that node? What if the first value that comes in is `10`? It won't get an entry in the adjacency list, and its neighbors won't be added in either since you perform the `null` check to see if an entry even exists.

Comment: You are right. Answer updated again. I think he needs to change the `addVertex` signature. Feel free to edit the answer if you think it will be good.

Comment: Using a `HashMap` will take `O(1)` time for insertion and linear time in the case of collisions for a particular key.

Comment: Indeed, this is why I mentioned `O` complexity. And I also mentioned "sequential indexing". If inserted in sequence, you avoid this problem. But I guess this is not the case, is it?

Comment: Right. You're not gaining anything with sequential indexing; you'll need something else to map the node value to its "sequential index". If that's the case, you're better off using a map in the first place to map a value to its adjacency list.

Comment: Added this as a second update. Thanks for the whole conversation, happy to have discussions like this!

Answer (score 0):

This is more of a code review comment, but :

1. Formatting - your IDE can do this (assuming you are using one..).
2. Use List rather than ArrayList, and Map rather than Hashmap, so `HashMap<Integer, LinkedList<Integer>> adj;` becomes `Map<Integer, List<Integer>>`
3. The method name `addeEgde` - c'mon!
4. You don't actually use the `ArrayList<Integer>` that you pass to the constructor of Graph - do you really need it?

From experience of implementing (far too many) graph objects, you might want to consider how you would make one that could use a fixed int matrix instead of the adjacency list approach. Both implementations can be useful, but in different circumstances.